# Unsure about whats my Gitlab instance domain name?

Tags: gitlab

New user to GitLab and trying to set my Project up for the first time.

I've setup Gitlab with docker and think (I've setup a local server for it using docker??).

I've then gone created my project and added a SSH key but when I try to use the command `ssh -T git@gitlab.com` it fails.

I think its because I have a different domain instance name.

My problem is: what is my domain instance name and how do I find out ?

To access gitlab I just type in localhost in the browser and besides that I think its linked to one of my emails but neither works in the command

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow, If one of the answers to your question is correct you should accept it.

Answer (score 0):

If your connection to the web GUI is `localhost` so your hostname/domain is the same for ssh connection.

You should make sure to open SSH port (22) to the container when you run it.
Add to docker run command `-p 2222:22` this map container port 22 SSH to host port 2222 because port 22 is taken on the host by SSH already.

Edit
 
Jest test it on computer
After you open port for gitlab container something like this.
`docker run -dit --name gitlab -p 2222:22 -p 8080:80 gitlab/gitlab-ce`
Note the `-p 2222:22` that probably what you missing.
 
You should be able to connect using ssh with this command 
`ssh -T git@localhost -p 2222`

Good luck.